# What is an effective close combat weapon in Quake Wars?

Tags: quake-wars

What is an effective close combat weapon in Quake Wars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lightning gun and machine pistol are my favorite close-range weapons.  Especially with the machine pistol, always be ready to switch to the pistol / blaster to avoid getting stuck reloading!

You can also try the shotgun / nailgun.  They were my favorite close-range weapons until one of the patches changed how they work.  I've seen them used effectively post-patch, but in much more capable hands than mine :)